# What is the (potential) drawback of using async functions everywhere?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am learning Javascript. This may sound like a crazy idea but I don't find clear answers on Google. Can I just replace all my regular functions/methods with `async function` everywhere? I mean there seems to be no downsides to this and it makes things so much simpler. Where the situation only involves synchronous steps, you just don't use `await` and it will work just like normal functions. Easy!

Personally I find having to distinguish `async` functions and normal functions unnecessarily burdensome. It's like driving a manual transmission car, where the car itself could easily handle the gearing by itself.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`async` functions always return `Promises`. This means that anytime you're *not* dealing with something asynchronous, you would have to convert the returned `Promise` into a value before you could use it. For example:

```js
const return4 = async () => 4;
console.log(4 + return4());
```

Instead, you would have to use the (unnecessarily wordy):

```js
const return4 = async () => 4;
(async () => {
  console.log(4 + await return4());
})();
```

(or call `.then` on the `return4` call before using it)

If `return4` was not `async`, on the other hand, of course `console.log(4 + return4());` alone would work just fine.

Another problem with `async` functions is that transpiling them to ES5 code (which allows for compatibility with obsolete browsers like IE) requires `regenerator-runtime`, which is *very* heavyweight. For example, transpiling the following single line with Babel:

```
const foo = async () => console.log('async!');
```

When you plug it into the [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl), you get:

```
"use strict";

function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) {
  try {
    var info = gen[key](arg);
    var value = info.value;
  } catch (error) {
    reject(error);
    return;
  }
  if (info.done) {
    resolve(value);
  } else {
    Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw);
  }
}

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
  return function() {
    var self = this,
      args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var gen = fn.apply(self, args);
      function _next(value) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value);
      }
      function _throw(err) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err);
      }
      _next(undefined);
    });
  };
}

var foo =
  /*#__PURE__*/
  (function() {
    var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(
      /*#__PURE__*/
      regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
        return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
          while (1) {
            switch ((_context.prev = _context.next)) {
              case 0:
                return _context.abrupt("return", console.log("async!"));

              case 1:
              case "end":
                return _context.stop();
            }
          }
        }, _callee);
      })
    );

    return function foo() {
      return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  })();
```

which also depends on `regeneratorRuntime` already being included in the script, which is 700-something lines of code that you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/blob/master/packages/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js).

On less powerful systems, this can result in a not-insignificant performance hit. This is why some (such as with the AirBNB style guide) prefer to never use `async` functions, even if they make the asynchronous control flow of the script clearer.