# JS Promises: Relationship between .then syntax and async/await (Apollo client example)

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, apollo

Sorry for the bad question format, but I just don't know what's wrong here: I'm attaching a JWT token to an Apollo client (using apollo-boost), like this:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/graphql',
  // adding the auth header to all requests
  request: async operation => {
    try {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession()
      const token = session.accessToken.jwtToken
      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
    } catch(e) {
      return
    }
  }
})
```

This works. However, when I tried to convert this to .then syntax which I like better, it didn't work anymore. This is how I re-wrote it:

```js
  request: operation => {
    Auth.currentSession().then(session => {
      const token = session.accessToken.jwtToken
      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      return
    })
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to *return* the promise if you want it to be chained/awaited by the caller.

Comment: `it didn't work anymore`, what didn't work anymore? and how didn't work any more?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async/await syntax is superior, try keep using that. If you have to target older browsers, I would suggest introducing a transpiler into your compilation pipeline instead of rewriting it to vanilla javascript by hand. If you are still interested in the "then" syntax, then here you are: the promise needs to be returned by the function.

```
request: operation => {
    return Auth.currentSession().then(session => {
       ... 
    }).catch(err => {
      return
    })
}
```

Comment: `async`/`await` *looks* cleaner, but it can introduce a lot of extra baggage when transpiled, and is sometimes not recommended for that reason. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347026/what-is-the-potential-drawback-of-using-async-functions-everywhere/51347160#51347160) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-airbnb (`async/await: regenerator-runtime is too heavyweight for our use, and async-to-promises is not yet complete enough to be safely used.`)

Comment: I feel like it also looks misleading sometimes. Makes it less clear that there is asynchronous code running and how it's running. But in this example the .then syntax is a bit weird. Anyways, now that I thought about it, it makes sense that you have to return. Thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see your point, although I have never seen a project where this was the most burning performance issue. Also I rather see it as a lack of good tooling. I wish Kneden took off... https://github.com/babel/kneden