# async vs sync event handlers performance

Tags: javascript, performance, async-await, event-handling, dom-events

I've created some tests of using async and sync event handlers. I've came to conclusion that using async handlers could make huge improvement in our code.

The only difference in the below two snippets is that in one, `customEventHandler` is `async`, and in that handler, it uses `await sleep(customEventHandlerSleepTime);` instead of `sleep(customEventHandlerSleepTime);`:

- async test:

```html
<body>
  <div id="event1">
    <div id="event2">
      <div id="event3">
        <div id="event4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  const customEventHandlerIterationsCount = 1000000;
  const customEventHandlerSleepTime = 500;
  const customEventName = 'customevent';
  const customEvent = new Event('customevent');
  const customEventHandler = async() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < customEventHandlerIterationsCount; ++i) {
      await sleep(customEventHandlerSleepTime);
    }
  };

  document.getElementById('event4').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event3').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event2').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event1').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);

  (() => {
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById('event4').dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Time: ', (end - start));
  })();
</script>
```

- sync test:

```html
<body>
  <div id="event1">
    <div id="event2">
      <div id="event3">
        <div id="event4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  const customEventHandlerIterationsCount = 1000000;
  const customEventHandlerSleepTime = 500;
  const customEventName = 'customevent';
  const customEvent = new Event('customevent');
  const customEventHandler = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < customEventHandlerIterationsCount; ++i) {
      sleep(customEventHandlerSleepTime).then(() => {});
    }
  };

  document.getElementById('event4').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event3').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event2').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);
  document.getElementById('event1').addEventListener(customEventName, customEventHandler);

  (() => {
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById('event4').dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Time: ', (end - start));
  })();
</script>
```

The result of the above tests are:

- async test execution time: ~1ms
- sync test execution time: ~1500ms

Am I doing something wrong or is it true? If we remove "await" and ".then()" from sleep function, the sync handler prints "Time" message faster with minimal difference of time.

Based on this test, I am wondering if it's better to always (or almost always) use async handlers, if we e.g. don't know what will be going on in nested functions of this handler or maybe if we don't use "await" in our handler directly it's better to avoid using async? Maybe there is a better way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing heavy processing in both snippets. The main difference is that in the second (sync) snippet, you're creating all Promises at once, *synchronously*. There are a large number of promises, so the overhead of creating so many is significant. In the first (async) snippet, when the event is dispatched and the handler runs, you only create *one* `sleep` Promise synchronously - this takes next to no time at all, and then the event finishes. Then, as a microtask, the second Promise is created, and you wait for it to resolve. Then, as a microtask, the third Promise is created, and you wait for it to resolve. Etc.

You're doing heavy processing in both snippets, but in one, it's staggered out over a long period of time (the Promises run in serial), but in the other, the Promises all run in parallel, being initialized immediately. *If* the event is fired via Javascript (rather than, for example, a native button click), it will take some time to get to the line *after* the manual firing of the event if all the heavy processing is synchronous.

So, sure, sometimes this async technique may help you (though, processing this intensive is pretty rare in Javascript, so often it won't be noticeable at all).

A better option would probably be to move the heavy processing into a web worker instead - that way, the processing is done on a *completely separate* thread.

Comment: If you could also answer to my comment in T.J. Crowder answer it will be very helpful. I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Nit: in the first snippet, the first `sleep(…)` promise is not created in a microtask, but right as part of the `customEventHandler()` call.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, that's the *you only create one Promise synchronously* part

Comment: Ah, I thought that would refer to the promise created by the async function call - so it's two promises created synchronously, then it waits for the first timeout.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no advantage to using `async` functions for DOM event handlers, all it does is add *(a very tiny bit of)* overhead.

What your test is missing is that the functions still take the same amount of time to run, they just do it **later**, after you're done measuring, so you don't see it. But they still take that time, and it's still on the main UI thread.

Comment: But are there any disadvantages of using async “always”? I mean, if we don’t know what will be going on in function called in handler (if we replace sleep function with something meaningful), e.g. any other developer could replace sleep function with his callback, we don’t know what will be doing during handler implementation.

Comment: @Marcin Synchronous functions are generally easier to deal with than async functions, and async functions return Promises that *may reject* (but all Promises should be handled appropriately, ideally - and event handlers do not handle the resulting Promise if there is one, they just call the handler). If you're doing something that would benefit from `await`, sure, use `async` (and handle possible errors with `try`/`catch`). Otherwise, the `async` is just noise. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347160

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Have a great day.